# Can I save only text via document.execCommand('Save As',...)? I'm always returned some HTML tags

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

Using the code below I can save a data locally in IE9 with Javascript. However, the file includes HTML tags when all I want to save is the text. How can I only save the text without the tags? Thanks

Code:

```
var doc = saveTxtWindow.document;
            doc.open('text/plain', 'replace');
            doc.charset = charset;
            if (fileName.endsWithAny('.htm', '.html')) {
                doc.close();
                doc.body.innerHTML = '\r\n' + textContent + '\r\n';
            } else {
                if (!fileName.endsWithAny('.txt')) fileName += '.txt';
                doc.write('mytext');
                doc.close();
            }

        var retValue = doc.execCommand('SaveAs', null, fileName);
        saveTxtWindow.close();
```

Output:

```
<! DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//w3c//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"><! DOCTYPE HTML>><HTML><HEAD><META content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http_equiv="Content-Type"></HEAD><BODY><PRE>mytext</PRE></BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be that 'text/plain' should actually be 'text/html'. The former outputs HTML tags and the latter just the text.